# Remove the Legend from nvd3 pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pie-chart, nvd3.js

Im working on creating a pie chart using nvd3. I successfully got the pie chart but when the number of slices increase the legends tend to take up lot of space and the pie shrinks. I have decided to remove the legends completely.

i tried somthing like

```
d3.select(".nv-legendWrap")
  .remove();
```

This hides the legends from being visible but the space is still blank. i want the pie to resize and take up the entire space. How do i do this??

The pie chart looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkIsG.png

I want the legends specified in the red block to be removed and the pie re-sized to fill the space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

what about hidden the legend by the moment of the creation of the chart:

> ```
>     nv.addGraph(function() {
>         var chart = nv.models.lineChart().margin({left: 100})
>       .useInteractiveGuideline(true)
>       .transitionDuration(350)
>       .showLegend(false)    // <-----Show the legend
>       .showYAxis(true)
>       .showXAxis(true);
> ```

Comment: Anytime Mani, please mark the question as solved. Thanks